# How check if website is gzip enabled or not?

Tags: php, curl

I' using curl to check if any given website is gzip enabled or not. 
I'm using the following code to check this.

```
$ch = curl_init('website name');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'SomeBull: BeingIgnored',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'
  )
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($info);
```

Each time result shows gzip option included in result. even those sites where gzip is not enabled like `http://pramitscomicsdump.com`  so can you advise what i'm doing wrong. I just need to check if gzip is enabled or not using curl.

I learned to use this command to check

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' 'site name'
```

but i'm unable to run this command in php.

Comment: i'm running this command  $res = shell_exec("curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate http://ww.google.com");

print_r($res);   but empty result

Answer (score 1):

Good effort with your code.

There are a few things to consider when checking for this:

1. Just because you ask for gzip, doesn't mean you'll get it, so you need to actually check the response headers to see if it was gzip compressed.  (Side note: Some pages on a site may use gzip, others might not, but there's a good chance the "home" page will).
2. You might want to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in case you're redirected.  If you are redirected, cURL will return multiple sets of headers so you'll want to check the headers from the final request.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // include headers in curl response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate', // request gzip
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'SomeBull: BeingIgnored',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'
  )
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    die('Error fetching page: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $info['redirect_count']; ++$i) {
    // split request and headers into separate vars for as many times 
    // as there were redirects
    list($headers, $response) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
}

curl_close($ch);

$headers = explode("\r\n", $headers); // split headers into one per line
$hasGzip = false;

foreach($headers as $header) { // loop over each header
    if (stripos($header, 'Content-Encoding') !== false) { // look for a Content-Encoding header
        if (strpos($header, 'gzip') !== false) { // see if it contains gzip
            $hasGzip = true;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($hasGzip);
```

Comment: I used google.com and got this error  "Error fetching page: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: @learner That's a whole other issue (you have outdated CA certs on your system).  For testing, you can get around it by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` to the code but this is BAD!  Instead, update your CA certs (plenty of answers about this exact error on SO).

Comment: it is not working for these sites, plagiarismcheckerx.com, leoexperts.com (i'm getting message false result )  while you can see here these are gzipped https://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fplagiarismcheckerx.com

Comment: Both show true for me on several different systems.  Have you tried any debugging to see why not?  http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/21de-rtin

Comment: code on phpfiddle showing true for those having gzip disable like  http://pentaloop.com/    you can check here   https://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpentaloop.com%2F

Comment: Fixed, and the error was pretty obvious. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vwmj-x9uh

Comment: yes it is working fine on phpfiddle but getting false for all websites on localhost while my curl version is  7.49.1, i debug it and found "Content-Encoding: gzip"  is not included in header when i run it on localhost.

Comment: here is example of header I received on localhost  "array(8) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(21) "Content-Length: 18753" [2]=> string(20) "Server: nginx/1.10.3" [3]=> string(35) "Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 02:51:52 GMT" [4]=> string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" [5]=> string(22) "Connection: keep-alive" [6]=> string(24) "Cache-Control: max-age=1" [7]=> string(38) "Expires: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 02:51:53 GMT" } "

Comment: It might not be sending the gzip request header. But if you pass it in the request headers, I don't know if curl would remove it if your version doesn't have zlib support built in. What host are those headers for?

Comment: K.  They all look the same for me except I get `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  What if you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1) ; curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));`  Can you show what headers you see in the debug outpu?  Also, in a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` script, can you show the curl build info?

Comment: you can see screenshot here having full detail  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7DI04psd_hBa0pvQllYMElxakk                    I added above 2 lines you mentioned, You need to zoom the picture.Thanks

Comment: Strange,  what if you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');` to the code and remove the `Accept-Encoding` header from `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Comment: same result. false